# If the number of edges in a spanning forest is $n-k$, then it has $k$ components.

Tags: graph-theory

> The following proposition about the number of components in a spanning forest of a graph $G$ has an easy inductive proof.  You are asked to provide it in the exercises.
>
> **Proposition 12.1**.  Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, and let $H=(V,S)$ be a spanning forest.  Then $0 \leq |S| \leq n-1$.  Furthermore, if $|S|=n-k$, then $H$ has $k$ components.  In particular, $H$ is a spanning tree if and only if it contains $n-1$ edges.

I am studying Graph Algorithms. I can solve the graph algorithm problems but I am confused with this proposition. If I were to prove this proposition, how would I start? Can anyone help here? Thank you.

Comment: Assume G is connected and H is a spanning tree. Then could you do the problem?

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of this proposition in the first place. That is why I was wondering the proof... :(

Comment: If you're having trouble parsing it, try looking up the words and symbols you don't know. What pieces of it do and don't you understand?

Comment: i am having trouble trying to come up with an example of this proposition. because I do not under stand it in the first place. I understand better with proof. so i was wondering this website could help with the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to illustrate what's going on:

[image: example graph and spanning forest]

By definition, a spanning forest is the union of a collection of vertex-disjoint trees that together span the original graph.  Since a $t$-vertex tree has exactly $t-1$ edges (see e.g. [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/414739/91818) for a proof), an $n$-vertex $k$-component forest has $n-k$ edges.

Since $H$ is assumed to be a spanning forest, the second part only says $H$ is a tree if and only if it has $n-1$ edges.