# Proof of connected graph having n-1 edge minimum with n vertices

Tags: graph-theory

How could I go about proving that for any connected graph with n vertices, the minimum amount of edges is n-1?

Comment: Check out www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf  for corollary 1.5.3.

Comment: Related: [Proving that each graph contains a spanning tree?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97567/proving-that-each-graph-contains-a-spanning-tree).  Note that a graph must be connected to have a spanning tree, and that the number of edges in a spanning tree is always [one less than the number of vertices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567713/if-the-number-of-edges-in-a-spanning-forest-is-n-k-then-it-has-k-components).

Comment: You could go about it by searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason is that any connected graph contains a spanning tree, and a spanning tree always has exactly $(n-1)$ edges.

This is not a proof, but it points you in the direction of a proof: Consider the following procedure:

<0> Initialize $U = \phi$, the empty set.

<1> Choose an arbitrary vertex $v$ and add it to $U$.

<2> $G$ is connected, so there is an edge from a vertex in $U$ to some vertex $z \notin U$. Add $z$ to $U$.

<3> Repeat step <2> until $U=V$. Note that this takes exactly $(n-1)$ steps.

Note that this is an algorithm for constructing a spanning tree.

Consider $E(U)$, the set of edges between vertices in $U$. Now, since we repeat step <2> $(n-1)$ times, and each time we add at least one edge to $E(U)$, it follows that by the end of the procedure $E(U)$ contains at least $(n-1)$ edges.