# L(G) is isomorphic to G iff G is a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

The converse is pretty obvious. If G is a cycle,  then it is isomorphic to it's line graph.
How to prove that if L(G) is isomorphic to G, then G is a cycle...?

**P.S.**- Assume G is connected

Comment: @bof I believe it is... please check

Comment: @joriki I must be falling asleep. Sorry.

Comment: @bof yup. Thanks. I have edited it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vertex of $G$ of degree $d_i$ contributes $\binom{d_i}2$ edges to $L(G)$. Then with $n$ denoting the common number of vertices and edges of $G$ and $L(G)$,

$$
\sum_id_i=2n\;,
$$

$$
\sum_i\frac{d_i(d_i-1)}2=n\;,
$$

so

$$
\sum_id_i^2=4n
$$

and thus

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(d)&=E[d^2]-E[d]^2
\\
&=\frac{\sum_id_i^2}n-\left(\frac{\sum_id_i}n\right)^2
\\
&=4-4
\\
&=0\;.
\end{align}

Thus all vertices in both graphs have the same degree $2$, which is only the case in a union of cycle graphs.

Comment: Thanks man superb. I mean i knew the relations that you have used. But i didn't think about using the concept of variance to show that the degrees are equal(especially solving a question in graphs!!). How did you come up with this? Do you know of some other questions where this can be used??

Comment: @idpd15: Concepts from probability are often useful in graph theory; e.g. both examples in the Wikipedia article on [the probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) are about graphs. In the present case, I realised that the degree sum is fixed and we can count the edges in $L(G)$ by adding up $\binom{d_i}2$, which is a convex (quadratic) function of $d_i$. If $\sum_id_i$ is fixed, the sum over a convex function of $d_i$ is minimal if all $d_i$ are equal. I could have just written that, but I translated it into the variance speak to make it more concrete.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a connected graph on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges and suppose $G$ is isomorphic to its line graph $L(G)$.  Then, $m=n$ and so $G$ is a connected graph having $n$ edges.  This implies $G$ is of the form $T+e$, where $T$ is a tree and $e$ is an edge not in $T$.  If $G=T+e$ is the $n$-cycle graph, then we are done.

So suppose $T+e$ is not a cycle.  Then, $T+e$ has a vertex of degree 3 or more. Three of the edges incident to this vertex in $G$ form a cycle of length 3 in $L(G)$.  Also, the unique cycle in $G$ obtained by adding edge $e$ to the tree $T$ induces a cycle in $L(G)$. Hence, $L(G)$ has at least two cycles.  We showed that $G$ has only one cycle and that $L(G)$ has two or more cycles, which is a contradiction because $G \cong L(G)$.  So this case is impossible, and $T+e$ must be a cycle.

Comment: Nice! How do you guys come up with such solutions!!?

Comment: Someone might need the result [If a graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges there must a cycle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414733/if-a-graph-with-n-vertices-and-n-edges-there-must-a-cycle)