# Question about a function from a graph to its line graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and let $L: G \to L(G)$ where $L(G)$ is the line graph of $G$.

1. Prove or show a counter example to the following:

a. $L$ is onto.

b. $L$ is one-to-one.

2. Determine all the fixed points of $L$.

I am stuck and would like a hint or some direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $L: G \to L(G)$? The notation $f:A\to B$ makes sense only if $A$ and $B$ are sets, and neither $G$ nor $L(G)$ is a set. Graphs aren’t sets.

Comment: You say you are stuck. What have you tried so far? What’s worked and what hasn’t? What **do** you know about these three parts of the problem?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum thats why I am having such an hard time , the question says that L is a function that moves a graph G to its line Graph L(G), then they are asking the questions : is L onto etc.... I am having an hard time even to begin with.... what is a function that moves G to L(G) acts on? its vertcies? edegs? ...

Comment: Well, does that notation involving $f$ come from the source (book?) where you found the problem, or is it yours? They might have in mind a function from some set of graphs, like, say $\{G = (V,E) : \mbox{$V$ is a set and $E\subseteq{V\choose 2}$}\}$, to another.

Comment: If so, then what might make a suitable codomain for that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I presume $G$ is the set of all graphs and $L(G)$ is the set of all line graphs. That seems to be a logical interpretation of your question.

1a) For onto, I refer you to Beineke's classical result.

*Beineke, L. W.*, [**Characterizations of derived graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(70)80019-9), J. Comb. Theory 9, 129-135 (1970). [ZBL0202.55702](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0202.55702).

> Any graph with any of the nine graphs (in the paper) as induced subgraphs will suffice.

1b) For one-to-one

> $K_{1,3}$ and $K_3$ are not isomorphic but $L(K_{1,3}) = L(K_3) = K_3$.

2a) For fixed points, there are many ways to do this. I refer you to [L(G) is isomorphic to G iff G is a cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832080/lg-is-isomorphic-to-g-iff-g-is-a-cycle).

> The fixed points are disjoint unions of cycles.