# If there are more edges than vertices in a connected graph then there is a cycle in the graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a simple question and probably stupid in graph theory:

> Prove that if there are more edges than vertices in a connected graph then there is a cycle:
>
> Let $G=(V,E)$ a connected graph,where $|V| \le |E|$.Prove that there is a cycle in the graph.

How can I prove that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges there must a cycle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414733/if-a-graph-with-n-vertices-and-n-edges-there-must-a-cycle)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a vertex of minimal degree. If the degree was $1$, then we're done by induction if we remove that vertex. Otherwise, the minimal degree in the graph is at least $2$. Take a longest path $v_0 v_1 \dots v_k$; then $v_0$ has degree $2$ or higher, so the only way this can be a *longest* path is if $v_0$ is connected to some other $v_i$ than $v_1$. (If not, if $v_0$ is connected to $x$ which is not a $v_i$, then we could extend the path by adding $x$.) So we have found a cycle.

---

Why is there a longest path? There is certainly a path of length $1$ (pick any vertex!). There are only finitely many paths, since there are only $|V|$ vertices. So we can just list the paths, and their lengths; at least one of them will have longest length (because every finite set has a maximum).

---

Question for you: where have we used that the graph was connected?

Comment: When you assume that there is such long path?

Comment: @TakaTiki Added to the answer.

Comment: I meant,that we have used the fact that the graph was connected when you assumed that there is such a long path?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your comment :) Note that if the minimal degree is $0$ then we can proceed by induction, removing any degree-$0$ vertex. So I don't think we need to use connectedness at all.

Comment: I understand that when you say "remove that vertex" we are going to a subgraph $H$ without that vertex, and then you take a longest path in $H$. But you cannot assert that the extremes of this path have degree $>1$, since some of them could be connected to some 1-degree vertex in the supergraph. What am I missing?

Comment: @PedroAlves Remove that vertex; then find a *cycle* inductively (not a longest path, though the inductive "find a cycle" process may involve finding a longest path in the reduced graph).

Comment: @PatrickStevens So, I will walk through subgraphs removing every 1-degree vertex until finding some with $\delta \geq 2$? What guarantee do I have that this will happen?

Comment: @PedroAlves Every graph has a vertex of degree $\geq 2$ unless it's disconnected or the tree on two vertices (which is forbidden by $|V| \leq |E|$). Note that removing a degree-$1$ vertex removes exactly one edge and exactly one vertex, so it doesn't change the fact that $|V| \leq |E|$ from the original graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n := \vert V \vert$.
Since $G$ is connected, there is a walk $\gamma$ passing through all $n$ points of $G$ and having at least length $(n-1)$.
If $\gamma$ has length $> (n -1)$ there is a vertex that $\gamma$ passes through twice, implying that it contains a cycle.
If its length is exactly $(n-1)$ there is some edge $e \in E$ which is unused in $\gamma$ (since $\vert E \vert \geq n$) and by combining it with $\gamma$ we get a cycle.

---

You can now use this to show that any graph with $\vert V\vert \leq \vert E \vert $ contains a cycle.

Let $G_k = (V_k, E_k)$ denote the connected components of $G$ and assume that $\forall k: \, \vert V_k \vert > \vert E_k \vert $. Then we have
$$
  \vert V \vert = \sum_k \vert V_k \vert > \sum_k \vert E_k \vert = \vert E \vert
$$
which contradicts $\vert V\vert \leq \vert E \vert $. So there must be a connected component $G_k$ with $\vert V_k \vert \leq \vert E_k \vert $, which then contains a cycle by the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph, where $|V|≤|E|$.
Assume that $G$ has no cycles.
Since $G$ is connected and has no cycles, $G$ must be a tree.
But in a tree, $|E|=|V|-1.$
i.e. $|V|>|E|$, which is a contradiction.
Thus our assumption is false.
Therefore, $G$ has a cycle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).